# Empty Table when running R script on Power Bi

Tags: r, powerbi

When running a simple R script adding two columns, the output I get is always "The table is empty" [as here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHs3V.png).

My table is pretty simple, only 3 columns: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VBxy.png)  and the script I am using is also very simple: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXXKC.png)

Where is the source of the problem? Any help would be appreciated.